# The asymptotic limit of a certain counting measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $P=(p(1),p(2),\ldots,p(i),\ldots)$ be a discrete probability distribution on $\mathbb Z_+$. Thus, $p(i) \ge 0$ for all $i$ and $\sum_i p(i) = 1$. Moreover, assume for simplicity that $p(1) \ge p(2) \ge \ldots$.

Let $i_1,\ldots,i_T$ be an iid sample from $P$, and for any $i \in \mathbb Z_+$, let $n_T(i) = \#\{t\, \mid\, i_t = i\}$ be the number of times $i$ occurs in the sample. Also define $N_T := \#\{i \, | \,n_T(i) \ge 1\}$, the number of distinct $i$ which occur at least once. Finally, define a probability distribution $P_T=(p_T(1),p_T(2),\ldots)$ on $\mathbb Z_+$ by

$$
p_T(i) =
\frac{1}{N_T}\begin{cases}
1,&\mbox{ if }n_T(i) \ge 1,\\
0,&\mbox{ else.}
\end{cases}
$$

**Question.** When $T \to \infty$, does $P_T$ have a limit in some sense ? If yes, how is this limit related to the base distribution $P$ ?

For illustrative purposes, consider the case where $p(i) = i^{-(1+\alpha)}$ for all $i$, where $\alpha \gt 0$ is a constant.

### Observations

- $\mathbb E\,1[n_T(i) \ge 1] = \mathbb P(n_T(i) \ge 1) = 1 - (1-p(i))^T$.
- $n_T(i)/T \to p(i)$.
- $1 \le N_T \le T$.

### Update: Case of finite support

Suppose $P$ has finite support with $N$ atoms. In this case, $P_T$ converges to the uniform distribution on this support.

Informal argument: If one conditions on $n_T(i) = k$ for some $i \in [N]$ and $k \in [0,T]$, then $1[n_T(j) \ge 1] = Bern(1-(1-p(j))^{T-k})$ for all $j \ne i$, while $1[n_T(i) \ge 1] = 1$. Thus, $N_T = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^N Bern(1-(1-p(j))^{T-k})$. Now, in the limit when $T \to \infty$, one has $ (1-p(j))^{T-k} \to 0$ for all $j \ne i$. Thus, $N_T \to 1 + N-1 = N$ and $n_T(j) \to 1$. We deduce that $P_T \to U([N])$.

Comment: I suppose that you mean $p(1) \geq p(2)$ and not $p(2) \geq p(2)$. But I am wondering whether this is an assumption you take in addition to $p$ being a probability distribution?

Comment: Typo. Fixed. Yes, that assumption is just to make life easier.

Comment: I think that there are two distinct cases to consider. Perhaps, try to think about the following: what happens with $N_T$ if $p(i) > 0$ only for a finite number of $i\in\mathbb Z$, and what happens with $N_T$ if $p(i) > 0$ for infinitely many $i$.

Comment: Intuitively, in the first case, $P_T$ convergences to the uniform distribution on the support of $P$.

Comment: Can you make this rigorous with your observation? What about the other case?

Comment: My argument  goes like this roughly. Let $N$ be the size of the support of $P$. If you condition on $n_T(i) = k$ for some $i \in [N]$ and $k \in [0,T]$, then $1[n_T(j) \ge 1] = Bern(1-(1-p(j))^{T-k})$ for all $j \ne i$, while $1[n_T(i) \ge 1] = 1$. Thus, $N_T = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^N Bern(1-(1-p(j))^{T-k})$. Now, in the limit when $T \to \infty$, one has $ (1-p(j))^{T-k} \to 0$ for all $j$. Thus, $N_T \to 1 + N-1 = N$ and $n_T(i) \to 1$. We deduce that $P_T \to U([N])$.

Comment: Here's my hunch: if $P$ has infinite support, then $p_T(i)$ will tend to $0$ uniformly over $i\in\Bbb Z$ as $T\to\infty$ (since $N_T\to\infty$ almost surely). I think this is inconsistent with any limiting probability distribution.

Comment: @dohmatob I think you might be able to go an easier way by using the observation $n_T(i)/T \to p(i)$. This gives you immediately that $n_T(i) > 0$ eventually iff $p(i) > 0$. This should also give you an argument for the claim by Greg Martin :)

Comment: The problem goes even deeper. Imagine you would like to distribute points uniformly in $\mathbb R^2$. How would you do that? For a finite volume, that is easy, you can simply take the uniform distribution. But when you take the volume to infinity, the same thing happens: all probabilities vanish and you don't get a probability distribution! If this related question is of interest of you, you might want to look up "Poisson point processes".

Comment: Thanks to all for the input. My hope was that it probability converges to some weird but well-known process. Also note the "reference-request" tag.

Comment: A related question (quantitative) https://mathoverflow.net/q/453384/78539